'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package' when QGIS-Plugin code running in PyCharm
I have created a 'raw' plugin with the pluginbuilder. The structure is as follows:

It runs perfectly when opened in QGIS.
However, when I open the plugin-folder as a pycharm project and run the script 'reformat_LK.py', which includes an import of the resources.py, I get the following import error:
from .resources import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

When I delete the dot from .resources the script runs without any errors, but then the plugin doesn't work in QGIS anymore.
Is there a way to fix it? And what is the reason for it?
